# Drupal 7 treat html 5 data attributes as text

Tags: 7

First I wound like to clarity i am not asking for code.

This code work on html 5.

I create basic page in drupal and implement same code:

```
<div data-top="opacity: 1" data--400-top="opacity: 0" class="abc"></div>
```

Drupal treat data as text and print this:

data-top="opacity: 1" data--400-top="opacity: 0" class="abc"

Do I need any module to enable html5 data attributes?

I am using FULL HTML and I have no idea how to solve.

Many Thanks.

Comment: make sure to change the input format as "FULL HTML"

Comment: Yup I am using FULL HTML or else other code dun work as well.

Comment: Are you using a WYSIWYG? If so which one?

Answer (score -1):

I am not using this module. Try once this module, hope you will get some configuration settings.

1. [HTML5](https://www.drupal.org/project/html5)

> This theme will be the official back-port of the theme-related work
>   done in the Drupal 8 HTML5 initiative. We want everyone to be able to
>   preview what's coming in Drupal 8 from a markup and CSS perspective.
>   We want anyone to be able to easily review our progress without
>   needing to create another install of an unstable, or unfamiliar
>   version of Drupal.

2. [HTML5 Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/html5_tools)

> HTML5 Tools is a module that allows Drupal sites to be built using
>   HTML5 ... smartly.
>
> One of our goals is to provide as much support for HTML5 markup in a
>   set of Tools provided by a module so that you can use this module with
>   any HTML5 theme you'd like.

3. [HTML5 Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/html5_media)

> This project has one goal. To bring a standardized, Open Source GPL
>   front end media solution to Drupal core. This project is completely
>   open and has no other intentions other than to provide a standard
>   front end media solution that will benefit the entire Drupal
>   community, so therefore, whoever would like to help in this initiative
>   is welcome to contribute!